# Visual sorting of files by name in ~/Documents

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, file-sorting

I have lot of documents in my ~/Downloads folder. Why the documents are not sorted by default in alphabetical order? Is there anyway to organize them so? Only on ~/Desktop I see an option for organizing documents by name.

Comment: Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `~/Downloads` or `~/Downloads` folder in *Files* application. Click the button next to the search button at the top right corner of the window. You'll get various sorting options including sorting by name.